# Compare welfare in Sweden vs Denmark

Tags: sweden, social-security, denmark

Where can I find a detailed and up to date comparison of the welfare system in Sweden and Denmark. I am looking for the differences between each of the countries and trying to find which country offers the best bang for the tax buck.

**Edit :** I am specifically looking for comparisons of welfare for medical expenses (doctor visits, medicines, surgery), kids (schooling, support payments, nutritional payments) and education (kids and adults).

Comment: This question seems to be too broad.

Comment: @gerrit updated question

Comment: Still too broad.  And what is "medicare"?  Medicine / healthcare portmanteau?  "Kids" is also very broad.